# auto scroll using animated UIScrollView.setContentOffset with NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nstimer

I'm writing a music player using Swift, but when I'm tried to auto scroll the lyric, I found something weird.

I use a NSTimer to trigger the scroll:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "updateTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

func upadate is:

```
let offset = lyricScrollView.contentOffset
lyricScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offset.x, y: offset.y + 25), animated: true)
```

but when I change the time interval to 0.1 like this:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "updateTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I found that my scrollview doesn't scroll 10x faster than before, instead, it scrolls a little every 0.1 seconds, not 25 points every 0.1 seconds. If I set animated to false, the problem is gone.

Could someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: When you say that it scrolls a little, how little is a little? Over the course of 1s does it scroll more when the interval is set to 1s or 0.1s? How long is the animation? Does it scroll faster if you set the scrolling to not animate?

Comment: It scrolls 4 to 6 every 0.1s, and if I set animated to false, it scrolls faster than animated = true.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to animate something that's already animating. Try changing the content offset every 0.02s and set `animated` to false.